# How do I draw polygon in agm map based on Input co-ordinates in Angular?

Tags: angular, google-maps, agm-map

I want to draw a polygon in the Google maps based on the co-ordinates input in the input box.

After entering the set of co-ordinates in the input box, once I click on Draw polygon button, I would like to draw a polygon in the Google map(agm map).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on a 3rd party library (AGM), you can actually just implement Google Maps API natively on Angular. This way, you can just follow the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) once you initialize Maps JS API. This should save you a lot of headache instead of following unpredictable [3rd party documentations](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core).

Here is a sample code with your requirements: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon

You can also just see the code below:

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

**mapComponent.html**

```
longitude: <input placeholder="longitute" name="longitute" [(ngModel)]="longitute" required >
<h2>Coordinates:</h2>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let coordinate of coordinates">
      {{ coordinate.lat }},{{coordinate.lng}}
    </li>
  </ul>
<button type="submit" (click)="onAdd()">Add coordinates</button>
<button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Draw Polygons</button>
<div #map class="map"></div>
```

**mapComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
declare const google: any;

@Component({
  selector: "my-maps",
  templateUrl: "./simple-map.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./simple-map.component.css"]
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("map", { static: true }) mapElement: any;
  map: any;
  latitude: number;
  longitute: number;
  coordinates = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const mapProperties = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8569, 151.2152),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(
      this.mapElement.nativeElement,
      mapProperties
    );
  }

  onAdd() {
    var stringToJson = JSON.parse(
      '{"lat":' + this.latitude + "," + '"lng":' + this.longitute + "}"
    );
    this.coordinates.push(stringToJson);
    this.latitude = null;
    this.longitute = null;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: this.coordinates,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    polygon.setMap(this.map);

    // Create the bounds object
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Get paths from polygon and set event listeners for each path separately
    polygon.getPath().forEach(function(path, index) {
      bounds.extend(path);
    });
    console.log(bounds);

    // Fit Polygon path bounds
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
```

**style.css**

```
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map {
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Just to add, if you ever receive an error "Google is not defined", just type a blank space anywhere (i.e. mapComponent.ts). That's a problem with StackBlitz as far as I'm concerned.